# Ruby: Turn an array of arrays into a hash with 3 key value pairs

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

Ok started over, apologies for my verbose and poorly structured original post.

My question is basically this:  is it possible to take an array of arrays and divide it into three equal-ish parts, sending each part to a hash where there are three key value pairs as described below?

Sample input:  an array of arrays like:

```
orig_array = [[13, 11, 19, 17, 12, 5, 3], [3, 9, 2, 20], [5, 21, 15, 4], 
[18, 14, 16, 10], [6, 1, 8, 7], [15, 4, 17, 6], [3, 19, 13, 14], [9, 21, 12, 7], 
[20, 11, 2, 18], [8, 10, 1, 16], [10, 6, 21, 17], [15, 11, 14, 19], [13, 2, 9, 18], 
[5, 12, 16, 7], [20, 4, 1,8]]
```

Desired output:  a hash where each key is a number starting with 1 and counting up, and each value is one third of the array, like:

```
hash = { 1=>[[array of arrays containing first 1/3rd elements from orig_array]], 
         2=>[[array of arrays containing next 1/3rd elements from orig_array]]
         3=>[[array of arrays containing next 1/3rd remaining elements from orig_array]]}
```

To be clear, this is part of an exercise for a class.  The exercise is not to find a way to divide an array of arrays like this, I just feel like doing so could be part of one potential solution and am looking for guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the exercise. Is it an array of strings or an array of arrays? What would determine the grouping and keys when you transform it into a hash?

Comment: show us what you have tried sample input and expected output

Comment: I initially posted by mistake as I wasn't finished writing, you must have found this right away.  Anyway - I started with an array of strings, then I used the code above to create an array of arrays of strings.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, leave a comment as to why.  Anonymous downvoting doesn't help me learn how to properly use this forum.

Comment: @Chuck The grouping would be determined by the requirement that there be 3 lists.  The keys can just be numbers starting with 0 or 1 and counting up to 3.  I imagine there's an easy way I am missing to split an array into three parts, and send each part to a hash where the key = 1 (or "part one" - whatever) and the value is one third of the array I am splitting up.

Comment: @jrwalker14 I downvoted because you did not provide sample input, and expected output and you also originally did not include what you have tried, once you include you sample input and expected output in the question I would remove my downvote

Comment: How do I include sample input and expected output ? Are you looking for a screenshot from IRB

Comment: Sample input is an example of data that you might want to run through this function. Sample output is what that data would look like after its been run through the function. For example, if I wanted a function that incremented each number in an array by one, I might give the sample input `[1, 2, 3]` and the sample output would be `[2, 3, 4]`. Then people can say, "Oh, `array.map {|n| n+1}` will give you that output from that input."

Comment: @Chuck Thanks!  I will update with details tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def unique_group_of_three(array)    
    multiple = array.size / 3
    return "Your collection is too small" if multiple < 5
    multiples = [multiple, multiple *2]
    array = array.shuffle

    {
        :first => array[0...multiple].uniq,
        :second => array[multiple...multiples[1]].uniq, 
        :third => array[multiples[1]..-1]].uniq
    }
end
```

Comment: this is cool, thanks!  i just had to rearrange how line 2 is written to be `multiple = array.size/3` to get it to run without an error, and i took out the `array = array.shuffle` because i have code that shuffles earlier in the method.  Have to admit, I don't understand quite how this works yet but I'm working on it.  Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, line 2 was backwards.

array[0...multiple].uniq takes the first element of the array up to the element before the "multiple" element of the array and creates a new array out of those elements while Array#uniq removes any duplicates that may be within the array.

Comment: I think this has a bug where it drops elements for arrays whose length is not an even multiple of three, though that case isn't well-specified in the OP. Also, a version of this that doesn't drop elements but instead just has one bucket that's smaller than the others can concisely be expressed as `Hash[ array.shuffle.each_slice((array.length/3.0).ceil).map.with_index {|e, i| [i+1, e] } ]`.

Comment: modified for those dropped elements. Thanks